# Grails: how to call a service and the service name from a string

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I want to call services dynamically so the service name will get as a string value, we can list all the services names in the grails project by using the code below.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.metadata.GrailsPlugin

for (type in ['service']) {

   for (artifactClass in ctx.grailsApplication."${type}Classes") {

      def clazz = artifactClass.clazz

      def annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(GrailsPlugin)
      if (annotation) {
         println "$type $clazz.name from plugin '${annotation.name()}'"
      }
      else {
         println "$type $clazz.name from application"
      }
   }
}
```

Here we will get `artifactClass` of the service.Is there any option to call the service by using this idea.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bean for the service from the `applicationContext`

```
//inject application context bean
def applicationContext

//to use
applicationContext."${yourServiceName}".serviceMethod()
```

Comment: To add to his, if you have `grailsApplication` already, you can get the context via `grailsApplication.mainContext`.  I also prefer using the method call `getBean` as opposed to using string interpolation but that's personal rather than functional: `grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('yourServiceName').serviceMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bean of your service this way:

```
import grails.util.Holders
...
YourService yourService = 
(YourService)Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext["yourService"]
```

Comment: Consider elaborating a bit on your answer, this makes it easier for others to understand your solution.